# Joomla!: What do to add links in footer?

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-template

I wanted to add some (internal) links to the footer in a custom template,
how should I do this?
I'm very new to Joomla! and I don't know how to do this best.
I couldn't/don't want install plugins, it should simple work with built-in possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you need to so is add a new menu.

1. Log in to Joomla and select Menu Manager from the Menu menu
2. Create a new menu
3. Select the new menu in the Menu menu
4. Add menu items - internal links or what ever you want
5. Select Module Manager from Extensions meni
6. Create new Menu module, select the new menu and the footer position

You should be able to then style the menu accordingly with CSS.

Comment: Okay, I tried it similar but the received template was corrupt so these menus wasn't display but thanks anyway ;)!